# Show that $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ with $f(x)=x^2\log(1+x^2)$ is bijective.

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, logarithms, inverse-function

Define $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ with $f(x)=x^2\log(1+x^2).$
How can I show that $f$ is bijective and how can I get the derivative of the inverse function in $\log(2)$?

Best regards

Comment: can you see if that's one one function

Comment: Yes. I can see that. But how do I proof that f is bijective?

Comment: You simply need to show it is surjective. Given some non-negative real, is there a non-negative $x$ such that $f(x)$ is the chosen real?

Comment: You can show firwst that $g,h;[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ are both bijections where $g(x)=x\log(1+x)$ and and $h(x)=x^2$ then $f=g\circ h$ is a bijection.

Comment: Alternatively, take $g_1(x)=(1+x)^x,$ $g_2(x)=\log x$ and $h(x)=x^2$ then $g_1:[0,\infty)\to [1,\infty)$ is a bijection and $g_2:[1,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is a bijection and $h:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is a bijection so $f=g_2\circ g_1\circ h$ is a bijection $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We compute the derivative
\begin{align*}
 f'(x) =& 2x \log (1+x^2) + x^2 \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \\
=& 2x \left( \log(1+x^2) + \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right) \geq 0
\end{align*}
and we only get equality when $x=0$. Hence, the function is increasing, and therefore it is a bijection.

Now, to calculate the derivative of the inverse, consider the following
\begin{align*}
y=&f^{-1}(x) \\
f(y) =& x \\
f'(y)y' =& 1 \\
y' =& \frac{1}{f'(y)} \\
y' =& \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}
\end{align*}
So, evaluating the inverse derivative in $\log(2)$ means first finding that $x$ for which $f(x)= \log(2)$. We can easily see that $x=1$ suffices. Now $f'(1) = 2 \left( \log(2) + \frac{1}{2} \right)$, and hence $(f^{-1})'(\log(2)) = \frac{1}{2 \left( \log(2) + \frac{1}{2} \right)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=2x\log(1+x^2)+\frac{2x^3}{1+x^2}>0\;\;,\;\;\forall\,x>0$$

and from the above it follows the function is monotonic increasing and thus $\;1-1\;$ , and since it is differentiable and thus continuous, and $\;f(0)=0\;,\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty\;$ , it also is onto $\;[0,\infty)\;$ .

From the above, it follows it is invertible, and from the theorem on the derivative of the inverse function we get that

$$\left(f^{-1}\right)'(\log2)=\frac1{f'(a)}\;,\;\;\text{when }\;a\;\;\text{is such that}\;\;f(a)=\log2$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed so, little typo there. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you can easily get that $a=1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, of course I can...but I left that for the OP. Then came other answers and gave up the whole answer. Oh, well...

Answer (score 1):

By calculating the derivative of the function, $$f'(x)=2xln(x^2+1) + \frac{2x^3}{x^2+1}$$ you find that $f$ is a monotonic increasing function, because $f'(x)$ is always positive for $0< x<\infty$.
But if $f$ is monotonic, it is also injective.
Then consider $y s.t. 0<y<\infty$. You can see that $\forall y$, $f$ is definitely greater than $y$, and that is because $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \infty$.
And so, using the Intermediate values theorem you get that $\forall y\ \exists x\ s.t. f(x)=y$.
This means that $f$ is bijective.

To calculate the derivative of the inverse in $log(2)$ use the formula $$g'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$ where $g$ is the inverse of $f$.
You can see easily that $f(1)=log(2)$ so the value of the inverse's derivative when $y=log(2)$ is $\frac{1}{2log(2)+1}$.

Comment: This is almost an exact copy of the second answer and pretty similar to the first one, written both more than 40 minutes ago,  so what's the point...?

Comment: Sorry I was writing it without internet connession after reading the question and I didn't see the previous answers